# How to conditionally color specific rows in an AntD table

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd, ant-design-pro

I'm trying to color entire rows based on some data that comes from the data source of the table.

I have seen that you can use `rowClassName`, but don't quite understand how it works.

Would love some typescripts examples!  Thanks!

```
<Table
  columns={cols}
  dataSource={data}
  rowKey={(record: obj) => record.key}
  rowClassName={(record: obj) => record.amount == '0' ? <???> : ''}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example from our codebase:

```
import s from './styles.css'

useStyles(s)
...
 rowClassName={(_r, i) => (i % 2 ? s.odd : s.even)}
```

and in a css file:

```
.odd {
  background: color(var(--midnight-5) alpha(50%));
}

.even {
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
}
```

We use [Isomorphic style loader](https://github.com/kriasoft/isomorphic-style-loader)

Comment: `useStyles` with antd? what is it?